# Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512' from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on writing for a project that I'm working on. So, I've created a Unit Test Project to the solution.

When trying some simple tests I got the error message:

```
Message: Test method (method name) threw exception: 
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512' from assembly 'mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

I've tried to find a solution to the problem but have not found one that I could get to work.

Any ideas on a solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the version of .NET is the same between the unit test project and the other project(s) in the solution. You might also try creating the unit test project when you create your first project for the solution.

Comment: Thought I had done that, but apperantly no. One is .NET Framework and the other is the new .NETCoreApp. Gonna see if this solves the problem, THANKS :)